# Пустой массив `POST` в `php` при запросе `axios.post`

Tags: php, ajax, post, reactjs, axios

Возникла проблема при `POST` запросе с помощью библиотеки `axios`.

Вот сам `POST` запрос:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
    }
})
.then(function(response) {

    console.log(response);

})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Это код файла `ajax.php`.

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

А результат запроса пустой массив `data: Array(0)`.

Документация с примерами [здесь](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Иностранная версия вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/q/41368272/5441700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Visman правильно сказал про то что `axios` отправляет данные с заголовком `header('Content-Type: application/json');` потому и данные не попадали в `POST`.

И я нашел два решения для `POST` запроса с помощью  `axios`. Что бы отправлять на сервер данные нужного формата и с нужными заголовками.

Вот первый способ:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
    }
})
.then(function(response) {

    console.log(response);

})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Надо было явно задать параметр `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },`

А это второй способ с применением [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('firstName', 'Fred');
params.append('lastName', 'Flintstone');
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
    }
})
.then(function(response) {

    console.log(response);

})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

А здесь с помощью `URLSearchParams` создаем объект данных что бы отправить их в формате `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` а не `JSON`․

> Примечание: `URLSearchParams` не поддерживается всеми браузерами.
>   Поддержку броузеров `URLSearchParams` можете смотреть [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Comment: Разве urlsearchparams будет не в GET значении?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Как оно может быть в `GET` если я делаю `POST` запрос?

Comment: То и странно что обычно в GET передаются значения из URL, поэтому и уточняю. Видимо там такой механизм.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Прочитайте ответ внимательно там не в `URL` предаются, а просто с параметры формируются. а после методом `POST` передаются в сервер.

Comment: ищу по этому же вопросу, но не понял куда использована переменная params в этом примере?

Answer (score 5):

Принимайте данные из потока [php://input](http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) так как от клиента идет не массив переменных, а строка в json формате.

Пример:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

и дальше работаете как обычно с массивом $_POST

Comment: Понятно, но это альтернативный вариант. А как можно от клиента сделать этот запрос что бы на сервер пошёл массив переменных, так как оно идёт на пример в запросах сделанных на `jquery`?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, это не обходной путь, так как в массив $_POST попадают данные отправленные с Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded или multipart/form-data, а axios отправляет данные с Content-Type = application/json, которые достаются из потока `php://input`.

Comment: Я не говорю что вы дали не правильный ответ, но это точно альтернатива по скольку я нашел варианты отправки данных на сервер в нужном формате и с нужными заголовками. Но спасибо Вам, ваш ответ помог мне идти в нужном направлении.

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('user_id', 1);
params.append('text', "Привет аксиос");
console.log(params);

axios.post('api/index.php', params);
```

Коллеги читайте документацию  https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format