# Почему PHP скрипт не видит POST?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, axios

Я отправляю такой POST запрос:

```
await axios.post('https://example.com/script.php', {
    id: 1,
    page: 'test'
});
```

А в самом php скрипте я делаю так:

```
if ( !isset($_POST['id']) ) {
    ///это не POST
}else{
    //а это нужный мне POST
}
```

В итоге вообще не находит POST, как будто его нет.

Добавил в начале php скрипта код:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/test.txt', $data);
```

В итоге в файле `test.txt` записывается следующее:

> {"id":1,"page":"test"}

Но почему нет **$_POST** ?

Comment: Нашел решение вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457181/axios-posting-params-not-read-by-post Спасибо :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Пустой массив \`POST\` в \`php\` при запросе \`axios.post\`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692384/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-post-%d0%b2-php-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-axios-post)

Comment: Да, потому что оно отправляет данные в виде жсон.